# How can I get screenshot's from "Recent opened apps"?

Tags: java, android, taskmanager

Is possible to get full app screenshot from "Recent opened apps"?

 
I want to make MeeGo or Symbian similar task manager for Android.

[image: Symbian Belle task switcher]

Answer (score 3):

I doubt this is possible without running on a rooted phone.

The system recent tasks panel gets the thumbnails via this code:

```
final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)
mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
ActivityManager.TaskThumbnails thumbs = am.getTaskThumbnails(td.persistentTaskId);
```

But it seems `getTaskThumbnails` is a private method and only allowed to be accessed with system privileges.

Source: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/com/android/systemui/recent/RecentTasksLoader.java#RecentTasksLoader

Another option would be to use [`ActivityManager.getRunningTaks()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29) to get the list of running tasks, then use `RunningTaskInfo.thumbnail` to get a thumbnail of the app. However, it seems that always returns null.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the list of running tasks using AvtivityManager.getRunningTasks and use this to take the screenshots. Refer this project:
http://androidexample.com/Check_Current_Running_Activity_%7C_Task_%7C_Application_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=111&aaid=133

Comment: How could this be used to take a screenshot of a `RunningTaskInfo`?