# Get the "task manager" images

Tags: android, android-activity

On Android, after a long press on the left or right button (depending on phone), a menu (called "task manager" no ?) appears.

[image: Button press task manager]

This new screen appearing displays the applications you launched, with a sort of screenshot of the last thing this app displayed.

I am wondering where the generated images are stored on the phone?

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to check this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796543/how-can-i-get-screenshots-from-recent-opened-apps

Comment: @jbarat It does looks like, but i expect something like a folder where all the thumbnails are saved or something like this, does such a folder exists ?

Comment: No idea, but most likely you can't access it on a non rooted phone.

Comment: I'm expecting the OS to keep those ones in RAM

Comment: @jbarat yeah it's rooted, it's just writing an app to access these seem waaaay too much of a bother for the few times i'll need it. Thank you still